# Dockerfile not copying file to image - no such file or folder

Tags: docker, redis

What I am trying to achieve:

1. copy a redis.config template to my docker image
2. read .env variables content and replace the template variables references (such as passwords, ports etc.) with values from .env
3. start the redis-server with the prepared config file

This way, I can have multiple redis instances setup for local dev, staging and production environments.

---

I have the following folder structure:

```
/redis
--.env
--Dockerfile
--redis.conf
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:latest

COPY redis.conf ./
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install gettext
RUN envsubst < redis.conf > redisconf

EXPOSE $REDIS_PORT

CMD ["redis-server redis.conf"]
```

When I go to the redis folder and run `docker build -t redis-test .` everything builds as expected, but when I do `docker run -dp 6379:6379 redis-test` afterwards the container crashes with the following error:

> Fatal error, can't open config file '/data/redis-server redis.conf': No such file or directory

It seems that the redis.conf file from my folder is not getting correctly copied to my image? But the `envsubst` runs as expected so it seems that the file is there and the .env variables get overwriten as expected?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you missed the working directory in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error is that you've explicitly put the `CMD` as a single word, so it is interpreted as an executable filename containing a space rather than an executable and a parameter.  Split this into two words:

```bash
CMD ["redis-server", "redis.conf"]
```

There's a larger and more complex problem around when `envsubst` gets run.  You're `RUN`ning it as part of the image build, but that means it happens before the container is run and the environment variables are known.

I'd generally address this by writing a simple entrypoint wrapper script.  This runs as the main container process, so after the Docker-level container setup happens, and it can see all of the container environment variables.  It can run `envsubst` or whatever other first-time setup is required, and then run `exec "$@"` to invoke the normal container command.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
envsubst < redis.conf.tmpl > redis.conf
exec "$@"
```

Make this script executable on the host (`chmod +x entrypoint.sh`), `COPY` it into your image, and make that the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```bash
ROM redis:latest

COPY redis.conf.tmpl entrypoint.sh ./
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install gettext

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["redis-server", "redis.conf"]
```